# Display flickr widget in website

Tags: widgets, flickr

I'd like to display some photos with flickr on my website which could change dynamically

```
<iframe align=center src=http://www.flickr.com/slideShow/index.gne?user_id=my_id&tags=Grenoble frameBorder=0 width=500 scrolling=no height=500></iframe>
```

In this example my tag is Grenoble (a city). What I'd like is to be able do change that tag (to New York or Chicago for example) even if I don't have pictures with this tag.

(The aim of this is to display photos according to a city variable).

Comment: Does http://www.flickr.com/slideShow/index.gne?user_id=my_id&tags=Grenoble display anything. Have you tried putting quotes around the attribute, e.g. align="center" src="http..." etc.

Comment: What server side programming language are you using?

Comment: My mistake. My question wasn't clear enough. I've edited my post.

Comment: As @paulmorriss says, you **must** put quotes around your attribute values. Without the double quotes, the '/' (forward slash) in the src URL will break the HTML.

Answer (score 2):

You will have far more success if you use [the Flickr API](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/). That page also has working code in many different server side programming languages to help get you off to a good start.